# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException - don't know why

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, exception

In my Developer Console i received this error reporting:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: error code 10: disk I/O error
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(SQLiteDatabase.java:1777)
at android.webkit.WebViewDatabase.clearCache(WebViewDatabase.java:708)
at android.webkit.CacheManager.clearCache(CacheManager.java:605)
at android.webkit.WebViewWorker.handleMessage(WebViewWorker.java:199)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

There are no swlite database in my application, i use adMob, Facebook API and Google Maps api v2, anybody knows what this could be caused by? thanks

Comment: Well, it looks like *something* is using a web view, and requesting that the cache be cleared... and the cache is presumably stored in Sqlite.

Comment: Possible duplicate {http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009699/sqlitediskioexception-error-code-10-disk-i-o-error}

Comment: So is there something I can do to prevent the crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this url . it help you

```
Since you are using External Storage, your application must be aware of the External Storage state, which you can get via `Environment.getExternalStorageState()'.

You must only access External Storage when the state is MOUNTED.
```

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009699/sqlitediskioexception-error-code-10-disk-i-o-error)

Thanks

Comment: The problem is: I'm not actually using external storage, as you can see there are no references to my code in the stack, i wonder if it could be caused by adMob or something like that that's working out of my control.

Comment: @c0rtexx Why did you accept this if didn't solve anything for you?

Answer (score -1):

It seemed be an known bug of android. But have not get rid of it. Look here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sqlite.git/

and notice commit

42c3f41  Add more logging to track down disk I/O errors. by Jeff Brown - 10 months ago